# saving application settings vb2008

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I am developing an application, and i need to store some configuration settings, with time, i will need to add some more configuration settings.

Am thinking of three alternative to implement that will me easy to access without much coding and efficient

sqlite, xml, and application configuration file

But am concerned about security, because some personal data will be saved together.

Comment: If security is an issue sqllite sounds like a good option.  The app.config is an xml file and xml as you know is just text.

Comment: @Andrew i prefer sqlite too, but you know it cannot be password protected. i will use it anyways, but hope i could find some solutions to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally settled to using sqlite.